# Laravel 5 - Redirecting to same list view after deleting an list object - Change not visible

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a view (lets call it 'foo') which basically lists all articles of a user and displays a delete button like that:

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => 'contents/'.$content->id, 'method' => 'delete', 'class' => 'deleteForm']) }}
    {!! Form::submit("Deaktivieren",['class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-warning']) !!}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Edit: The Destory Function

```
public function destroy ($id){

    Content::findOrFail($id)->update(['expires' => Carbon::now(), 'active'=>false]);

    return redirect('foo');
}
```

So that the user sees the same page. But since laravel is caching the view, the old view (so with the deleted object) ist displayed.

Is their a smarter pattern to archive this effect? I thought about AJAX but are not really familiar with JS.

Thank you for your time and help,
Simon

Comment: post the deletion logic

Comment: @Adamnick done! hope it helps

Comment: how you are fetching the articles? are you making sure that you dont get those where active column is false if active is a column?

Comment: and this is the right way to open forms `{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) !!}
    //
{!! Form::close() !!}`

Comment: @Adamnick yes I do (the view only displays active articles) EDIT: I don't

Comment: @Adamnick thanks for the hint, did a coding error in create (all articles that are actually active had active=false and somehow I carried on this concept when writing my Scopes! Thank you for you help!

Comment: glad I could help. please post the answer or accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you dont get those articles where active column is false if active is a column.

and this is the right way to open forms 
`{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) !!} // {!! Form::close() !!}`

Comment: What wrong with {{ Form::open(['url' => 'contents/'.$content->id, 'method' => 'delete', 'class' => 'deleteForm']) }} ?

Answer (score 0):

If your view displays the same after changing an object on it from this view, you did not really change anything. Check if your data is different after the change from before the change.